# Reading txt file and convert to array then export in another txt forma using Python

Tags: python, arrays, file, export

`f = open('read.txt','r',)
     print f
     cont = f.readlines()
     print cont 
     y = np.zeros(30597 ,dtype=np.int16)
     x = np.zeros(30597)
     z = np.zeros(30597)
     t = np.zeros(30597)
     i = 0
     for line in cont:
     y[i], x[i], z[i], t[i] = line.split("\t")
     i = i +1 
     f = open('writeme.txt', 'w')
     for i in range(0,30597):
      f.write(x)
      i += 1
      f.close()`

I have an txt file i'm trying to read it from python and convert the four columns to array without the first 4 lines(units,x,y..) .

[image: input]

and export it later in another format

[image: output]

but i didnt get what i need, can some help please
thank you very much

Comment: Can you create input as txt or csv file?

Comment: Where is the code you have tried so far?

Comment: f = open('read.txt','r',)
print f
cont = f.readlines()
print cont  
y = np.zeros(30597 ,dtype=np.int16)
x = np.zeros(30597)
z = np.zeros(30597)
t = np.zeros(30597)
i = 0
for line in cont:
   y[i], x[i], z[i], t[i] = line.split("\t")

f = open('writeme.txt', 'w')

 
for i in range(0,30597):
 

   f.write(x)
    i += 1
    f.close()

Comment: this the code i was trying with, i can read easily the whole file but i can not seperate the coloms x, y and put it in array

Comment: import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f = open('read.txt','r',)
print f
cont = f.readlines()
print cont
y = np.zeros(30597 ,dtype=np.int16)
x = np.zeros(30597)
z = np.zeros(30597)
t = np.zeros(30597)
i = 0
for line in cont:
   y[i], x[i], z[i], t[i] = line.split("\t")

   i = i +1 
f = open('writeme.txt', 'w')
for i in range(0,30597):
    f.write(x)
    i += 1
    f.close()

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code you've tried and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**I could resolve my problem, it could be a solution one day for another programmer or engineer **

```
    import numpy as np 
    import pandas as pd



     data = np.genfromtxt('Input.txt', delimiter='\t')

    x1 = data[:,][3:,0]
    y1 = data[:,][3:,1]

    xLev1 = data [3:,][:,2]

    yLev1 = data [3:,][:,3]

     #export the data


 x1_col = x1.reshape(-1,1)
 x2_col = x2.reshape(-1,1)

 xLev1_col = xLev1.reshape(-1,1)
 xLev2_col = xLev2.reshape(-1,1)


  #print yn_col

   yLev_col1 = yLev1.reshape(-1,1)
    yLev_col2 = yLev2.reshape(-1,1)


     for i in range(0,len(xLev1)):


        #I110_Q634
         f.write(str(xLev1[i]+135.63)+";"+str((yLev1[i]-yLev1[0])*1000)+
          ";"+str(xLev2[i]+130.950)+";"+str((yLev2[i]-yLev2[0])*1000)+
           +"\n")


               f.close()
```